# Export a table under different name

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if it's possible to export a table using `mysqldump` (along with the data) but under a different name. For example I have `tablex` but I want to export it as `tabley`

Comment: r u trying to export via phpmyadmin or php code??

Comment: @diEcho: Neither, the question says `mysqldump` - a command-line executable which gives a very similar output to that of phpMyAdmin. http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysqldump

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All MySQLDumper does is create a text based file filled with SQL statements to recreate the database structure and insert each record.

Simply perform an SQL Dump, then open up the text file, and do a search + replace on the table you wish to rename.

Comment: @Gavin yeah I know but the file is pretty big (about 1 gb).. how should I "open it" ?

Comment: ok, that might be a bit of an issue with such a large file, but most text editors will give a good shot at trying to open it. I personally use Notepad++, but there are plenty more out there.

Comment: @Gavin .. I also run it on a redhat server so no gui available

Comment: try Vi or Emacs, depending on which camp you belong to, or even Nano, any text editor will work. Alternatively this command should do it without having to open the file: `sed 's/tablex/tabley/g' mysqldumperfile.sql`

Comment: @gavin you forgot to say that I should do sed 's/tablex/tabley/g' mysqldumperfile.sql > newfile.sql now I deleted the whole table

Comment: My appologies. I didnt have access to a linux system to try it. If this worked, can you click accept on the answer. Cheers.